# Is .Net program wait for sql table trigger response

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a .Net program which inserting the records into table and that table has trigger which inserting records via DBlink to another server.

In this case, inserting the records to the table in for loop.
Do the application wait for the response from trigger to complete the dblink transaction?

Because I'm getting the below error intermittently while inserting the record into the table. If insert one record I didn't get below error.

> Error Message "Row handle referred to a deleted row or a row marked
>   for deletion"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does not return until all triggers are complete, whether the trigger is "AFTER" or "INSTEAD OF".  The same behavior you see in SSMS is what you will get in your .Net application.  Consider this example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TriggerTest 
    ( Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , SomeValue INT NOT NULL );
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TriggerTest_AfterInsert
ON dbo.TriggerTest
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
    INSERT INTO dbo.TriggerTest ( SomeValue )
    SELECT i.Id + 1000 FROM Inserted AS i;
END;
```

Then execute the following in SSMS:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TriggerTest ( SomeValue ) VALUES  ( 5 );
```

SQL Server does not complete the execution until the more than 10 seconds have elapsed due to the delay of 10 seconds in the trigger.  Also, that is inherently part of the same transaction, so if something in the trigger fails, the original insert into the table will be rolled back.

Because of these behaviors, triggers should generally be avoided unless the logic in the trigger is very simple (like inserting an audit record into a corresponding audit table) and/or the developer understands the potential performance issues.